# Unir tres modelos para obtener datos en una vista. con MVC PHP

Tags: php, mvc

Estoy desarrollando una Web con PHP usando MVC sin ningún framework ni libreria. Tengo 3 modelos **Categoría**, **gasto**, **usuario**:

Quiero sacar en una vista los **usuarios** con sus **gastos** y a que **categoría** pertenece (las 3 tablas se relacionan entre si por el id).

Los modelos son los siguientes:

```
class UsuarioModel extends Model{

    private $id;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $name;
 
  //metodos construct, save, update..

}

class CategoriaModel extends Model{

    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $color;

  //metodos construct, save, update..

}

class GastoModel extends Model{

    private $id;
    private $title;
    private $amount;
    private $categoryid; //id de la categoria
    private $date;
    private $userid; //id del usuario

  //metodos construct, save, update..

}
```

Para sacar en una vista datos de los 3 modelos lo yo que pienso es que para ello necesito una consulta JOIN de SQL que relacione las 3 tablas, entonces entiendo que tendría que hacer un nuevo modelo llamado joinUsuarioGastoCategoria ¿y ahí hacer la consulta? ¿o cual seria la manera mas optima?

Gracias!

Comment: Es importante que indiques si estás trabajando con algún framework (Symfony, Laravel, etc). Lo digo porque generalmente los frameworks basados en ORM ya tienen formas estándar de hacer lo que quieres. Y, si estás diseñando tu propio contexto, podrías inspirarte en ellos para resolver este tipo de problemas.

Comment: Estoy trabajando con PHP "a pelo".

Comment: El $id es el $id de usuario en las tres tablas?

Comment: El $id es el identificador autoincremento de cada tabla